# Is it possible to have favorite tags trump ignored tags?

Tags: feature-request

I have four tags favorited and about eight or nine ignored. For example, [gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gimp) is ignored because I don't use it. The problem I'm finding is that if someone posts a question tagged with multiple tags—and one of those tags is something I've ignored—the question gets greyed out even if there are tags I am interested in. For a random example, here's a post tagged with [gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gimp) that has nothing to do with Gimp, really: [Is it easy to convert an image to a cartoon with high quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/is-it-easy-to-convert-an-image-to-a-cartoon-with-high-quality)

My feature request would be to allow favorite tags to trump ignored tags, if the user so wished (for example, the fact that the above question was tagged [adobe-photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) would highlight the post in my list, despite the fact it was also tagged [gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gimp)).

Comment: I'm rather sure we can't implement this on this site only. Relevant and possible good reads are http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140383/favourite-ignored-tags-conflict and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199193/more-advanced-favourited-ignored-tag-system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth noting that *both* favorite and ignored styles are applied, so you get the background color from the favorite and the lowered opacity from the ignored tag.

You can override the style with a user stylesheet easily enough (if you don't know how, Google *"[your browser] user stylesheet"*. On Chrome you can use something like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), I believe most other browsers can do it with no extensions).

This'll do it:

```
.tagged-ignored.tagged-interesting {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```